# Restrict lambdas on certain interfaces

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-bytecode

Assuming I have a couple of interfaces with exactly one abstract method. Having these interfaces, I can declare lambdas with it:

```
interface A {
    int c();
}

interface B {
    int c();
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        A a = () -> 42;
        B b = () -> 42;
    }
}
```

Short question: is there some trick or hack to restrict using interface `A` for lambdas and fail the build on attempt to do so? Any hint, dirty or not, is welcome (by 'dirty' I mean hacks on compilation/bytecode level - something which won't affect sources and, preferably, public contracts).

Long story: for some interfaces implementors I consider defining `equals/hashCode` as a part of the contract. Also, I generate `equals/hashCode` automatically for them at build time.

In this context, lambdas are troublemakers. For ordinary and anonymous implementors of interface `A` I can find a `.class` file and instrument its bytecode at build time. For lambdas there is VM-anonymous class, produced at run time. Affecting such class seems impossible at build time, so I need to at least prohibit such occasions for a specific set of interfaces.

Comment: I already described all reasons at "Long story". Isn't it detailed enough?

Comment: well a lambda can not have `equals` and `hashCode` as you can not define them at all, so why prohibit this interface from being used as a `@FunctionalInterface`?

Comment: @Eugene, imagine that having equals and hashCode defined is part of the contract served by interface `A`. Like it is saying in its javadoc - `all implementors of interface A must define equals and hashCode following this and that guidelines... tool X can generate them for you`. And then someone cames with lambdas and violently breaks the contract, and tool X can do nothing about it. When I defined interface `A`, I didn't supposed it to be the functional interface. I wanted it to be just an interface with one method.

Comment: why do you define hashcode/equals in the first place? so that you could put these types in a `HashMap` let's say, but since lambdas don't have those, putting them into such a structure will cause very weird behavior. My point is IMO tool X *should* not do anything about it at all. On the other hand there is no `@NotAFunctionalInterface` that would, at compile time, prohibit your usage. AFAIK you can not even make do anything about it as to get into the `LambdaMetafactory` and prohibit *some* interfaces not being treated as Functional

Comment: while on the same page - you could easily document this usage too instead of failing. Think keys and `HashMap` - you can alter the key *after* it has been inserted into the map, but the behavior is unspecified. Btw if I were the developer using whatever project you are doing I would be very surprised...

Comment: Why shouldn't I? Again - having equals/hashCode defined for all implementors of `A` is part of the `A` contract. Not a single word here about implementors of `A` being lambdas. So - lambdas doesn't have equals/hashCode? It's problem of lambdas, not of my interface `A`. If they can't fit my contract, then I'd prefer to ban them. Why my interface of one method must be functional? Why it can't be just an ordinary interface with one method?

Comment: unfortunately this is not me and your decision - this is how the language has evolved. I am not *telling* you what to do btw, just thinking about it. And also think what your are saying - forcing a hashcode/equals contract? Again, I would be very surprised to see this

Comment: last idea and I'm done :) if you so desperately want to enforce this, why not use an abstract class (if that is an option)?

Comment: About seeing equals/hashCode as a part of contract - IMO the presence of equals/hashCode in the contract of Object itself is nasty reality. But we live with that. I doubt that my approach will make situation worse than it is.
About abstract classes: well, you know, abstract classes are not equal replacement to interfaces. It will be hard to reconsider it now, and I don't kinda inspired of the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at my solution on that:

```
package com.example.demo;

public class LambdaDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //doesn't compile
        //LambdaRestrictedInterface x = () -> {};
        LambdaRestrictedInterface y = new Test();
        y.print();
    }

    private static class Test implements LambdaRestrictedInterface {
        @Override
        public void print() {
            System.out.println("print");
        }
    }

    public interface MyInterface {
        void print();
    }

    public interface LambdaRestrictedInterface extends MyInterface {
        @Override
        default void print() {
            //hack prevents lambda instantiating
        }
    }
}
```

https://dumpz.org/2708733/

Idea is to override parent interface with default impl

**Edit from originator:** After some consideration, I decided to accept this answer, (since it suited my needs the best and is rather cheap to implement) with some formal additions. In fact, it was realized that the *minimal* instrumentation which is enough to prevent interface being used as lambda-type is to just add default implementation to its abstract method.

Comment: Your example gave me a good hint. Theoretically, I can just make method of the interface `A` instrumented to be default and throwing some runtime exception - that will prevent it to be the lambda type. It will do the work pretty well. Drawback is that it is not so transparent for developer and slightly impact the code of the interface, but I think I can live with that.

Comment: yeah it's just matter of approaches applied in your company/team, that is if runtime exception is desired then it's ok :) i personally prefer compile time checking.

Comment: Of course, we all like type-safety and fail-as-fast-as-it-possible approach. But life is tough. I wonder why it was so hard to invent some sort of `@NonFunctionalInterface` in the beginning.

Comment: problem is that `LambdaRestrictedInterface` is not a `@FunctionalInterface` anymore  and since `MyInterface` is *still* public (and we don't have sealed interfaces yet), anyone can still use that as a lambda. I can't tell how this solves the problem, but I might have a slow morning...

Comment: The purpose of ```LambdaRestrictedInterface``` is to proxify black boxed MyInterface and substitute it in client code which requires lamda-less approach. On the other hand if you can access ```MyInterface``` directly you can get rid off ```LambdaRestrictedInterface``` and amend client code if it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

From playing around a bit, it looks like the `desc` field of the `invokedynamic` call contains the interface that's being implemented. For instance, when I created a simple `() -> {}` Runnable and then passed it through [ASM's Bytecode Outline](http://asm.ow2.org/eclipse/) plugin, the "ASM-ified" call looked like:

`mv.visitInvokeDynamicInsn("run", "()Ljava/lang/Runnable;", new Handle...`

So if you're able to do the build-time hack on the call site (as opposed to somehow marking the annotation itself as non-lambda-able, which I don't think you can do) then you should be able to first compile a set of disallowed interfaces, and then check the `invokedynamic`'s desc against that set.

Comment: (I'm putting this up as a community wiki since I haven't actually worked with this at all, and I'm providing only the germ of an answer.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got it. It seems workable. Annotating non-lambda interfaces is not actually a problem. I still have to determine the set somehow.

Comment: You can’t inject `hashCode`/`equals` methods into an interface, so you would have to redirect the lambda creation site to another bootstrap method capable of generating the desired implementation class (or supporting a specific superclass to inherit from). But it’s doable.